# What is this sliding door latch called, and where can I find it?

Tags: lock, sliding-glass-door, latches

I have a sliding door. The part that the the lock interacts with, on the wall, has broken. It looks like a double hook (pictures attached).

I went to home depot and no one knew what it was or where to find it. Does anyone have a clue?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find it.

It is called a '*Patio Door Keeper for Yale Ogron Sliding Glass Door*', by manufacturer **Barton Kramer**.

[Home Depot Link](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Barton-Kramer-Patio-Door-Keeper-for-Yale-Ogron-Sliding-Glass-Door-491/205649535?mtc=Shopping-B-F_D25H-G-D25H-25_4_BUILDERS_HARDWARE-Multi-NA-Feed-PLA-NA-NA-BuildersHardware_PLA&cm_mmc=Shopping-B-F_D25H-G-D25H-25_4_BUILDERS_HARDWARE-Multi-NA-Feed-PLA-NA-NA-BuildersHardware_PLA-71700000035978695-58700004046980559-92700044264784744&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIqbCnicK-6QIVyp6zCh206ApKEAYYASABEgKhLfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)